# Ignite UI IgCurrencyEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am trying to programmatically update a currency field to run the value changed event which holds a numeric calculation. I want the value to set to zero using something like.

```
$('.tester').igCurrencyEditor("setFocus");

$('.tester').igCurrencyEditor('option','value', 0);
```

Then when I blur out, or not sure what to do here, the `valueChanged` event should trigger as per the API docs (It can be raised on lost focus or on spin events).

But I can't seem to trigger the value changed event, it only works when I manually click into the input and change the number.

Comment: What is the version of Ignite UI that you're using?

Comment: Also, could you update the question with your editor configuration?

Comment: I'm using version 2015.2..  
  
my configuration is as follows  
  
  
    `tt.igCurrencyEditor({
    value: sel,  
    currencySymbol: "£",  
    valueChanged: function (evt, ui) {  
     //my code in here to trigger calculations  
    }});`

Comment: check the answer I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `valueChanging` and `valueChanged` events would trigger when a user interaction changes the `displayInput` value of the editor, and the corresponding `valueInput` value is different from the display input one. The editors have adopted the same approach as all other Ignite UI controls where events do not trigger on API calls, because when an API call is performed, the developer can choose whether to invoke their event handler after the API call, or not.

There's two things that you can do to invoke your event handler. First one is to cache the event handler method and invoke it manually:

```
$('.tester').igCurrencyEditor({
    ...
    valueChanged: valueChanged,
    ...
});

function valueChanged(event, ui) {
    // event handler
};

$('.tester').igCurrencyEditor("setFocus");
$('.tester').igCurrencyEditor('option','value', 0);
valueChanged(null, { /* if you need arguments */ });
```

The second one is to extend the currency editor and override the method that performs the check whether these events should be triggered, and make it always trigger the events:

```
$.widget("ui.igCurrencyEditorExtension", $.ui.igCurrencyEditor, {
    _processValueChanging: function (value) {
        this._triggerInternalValueChange(value);
    }
}
```

The second approach requires you to switch to using the `igCurrencyEditorExtension` and may cause side effects, as the method performs other checks as well.

Anyways, what Alex Marinov has suggested should work, but it depends on your editor configuration, depending on whether you've set nullValue, allow null values in the editor, etc.

Comment: Hi when i try to pass a function to the value changed method, when i trigger the function, event is null and ui is undefined, For instance  
I have this  
    `ValueChanged = function(event, ui) { 
   
        var newvalue = ui.newValue;`

  newValue is undefined..

Comment: Can i pass in the ui to the function? `valueChanged(null, whateverUi)`?  
When this is called from my click function i need to pass in a value, but i have set the targeted input using `var s = ui.editorInput[0];   var tt = $(s);`  to target a jquery attribute..on actual value changed by the user.

Comment: You can. You're invoking the method, so you can put whatever arguments you want. You can even make your method recognize when you called it manually like set `{ manual: true }` in the second argument, and then perform the check like this `if (ui.manual)`. You're setting the new value to `0`, so just pass `{ newValue: 0 }`.

Comment: I had a test earlier and i think it will work. I have other code that is encapsulated so it will need a good bit of tweaking. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need a function like this:

```
function clearValue() {
    $('.tester').igCurrencyEditor('option','value', "");
    $('.tester').igCurrencyEditor('field').blur();
}
```

The result will be that the displayed value inside the currency editor is "$0.00" and the valueChanged event is fired.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work, apparently its just not possible to fire the event programmatically which i think is crazy! I opened a case and a snippet of their response was this    
  
  
  ***"I have done an initial review of your case and the event do not fire when the API is used to set the value or etc that would normally trigger the event. The events only trigger when the control is interacted with through the UI."***

Comment: Have a look at this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gbnomw5a/4/
However, this will work only when you`re clearing the value inside the editor. If you try to set another value - the event will not fire. 
If this is your case, have a look at the answer that Konstantin Dinev has provided below.

Comment: This would work in theory, but i have to bind my click event through  
 `$(document).on('click')`  
  I tried this method with the function call inside but it didnt trigger the click 
  event for the currencyEditior.